# Android studio Kotlin plugin crashes constantly

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I constantly get exceptions while opening and editing files in my Android Studio project from the Kotlin plugin. There is a notification saying

> IDE Error Occured

and when I click on it it takes me to the "IDE fatal errors" reporting tool where it says:

> Exception in Studio core

The error message is the following:

```
Kotlin resolution encountered a problem while analyzing KtCallExpression
org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.resolve.KotlinIdeaResolutionException: Kotlin resolution encountered a problem while analyzing KtCallExpression
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.resolve.ResolutionFacadeWithDebugInfo.analyze(ResolutionFacadeWithDebugInfo.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.resolve.ResolutionUtils.analyze(resolutionApi.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.parameterInfo.ArgumentNameHintsKt.provideArgumentNameHints(ArgumentNameHints.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.parameterInfo.HintType$PARAMETER_HINT.provideHints(KotlinInlayParameterHintsProvider.kt:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.parameterInfo.KotlinInlayParameterHintsProvider.getParameterHints(KotlinInlayParameterHintsProvider.kt:161)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.hints.ParameterHintsPass.process(ParameterHintsPass.java:84)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.hints.ParameterHintsPass.lambda$doCollectInformation$0(ParameterHintsPass.java:76)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.hints.ParameterHintsPass.doCollectInformation(ParameterHintsPass.java:76)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:70)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1137)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:430)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:429)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:405)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:143)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:218)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:403)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:170)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Recursion detected on input: onCreate under LockBasedStorageManager@42a2e9fb (<unknown creating class>)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.computeDescriptorsFromDeclaredElements(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:195)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope$descriptorsFromDeclaredElements$1.invoke(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope$descriptorsFromDeclaredElements$1.invoke(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:410)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getContributedDescriptors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorUtils.getAllDescriptors(DescriptorUtils.java:593)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.resolveMemberHeaders(LazyClassDescriptor.java:573)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.doForceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:543)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.lambda$new$4(LazyClassDescriptor.java:221)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.forceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:539)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.IDELightClassContexts.contextForNonLocalClassOrObject(IDELightClassContexts.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.resolve.IDELightClassGenerationSupport$createDataHolderForClass$3.invoke(IDELightClassGenerationSupport.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.resolve.IDELightClassGenerationSupport$createDataHolderForClass$3.invoke(IDELightClassGenerationSupport.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassDataHolder$exactResultLazyValue$1.invoke(LazyLightClassDataHolder.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassDataHolder$exactResultLazyValue$1.invoke(LazyLightClassDataHolder.kt:32)
    at kotlin.SafePublicationLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassDataHolder.getJavaFileStub(LazyLightClassDataHolder.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassDataHolder$LazyLightClassData$clsDelegate$2.invoke(LazyLightClassDataHolder.kt:103)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassDataHolder$LazyLightClassData$clsDelegate$2.invoke(LazyLightClassDataHolder.kt:100)
    at kotlin.SafePublicationLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassDataHolder$LazyLightClassData.getClsDelegate(LazyLightClassDataHolder.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.classes.KtLazyLightClass$clsDelegate$2.invoke(KtLazyLightClass.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.classes.KtLazyLightClass$clsDelegate$2.invoke(KtLazyLightClass.kt:23)
    at kotlin.SafePublicationLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.classes.KtLazyLightClass.getClsDelegate(KtLazyLightClass.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.classes.KtLightClassForSourceDeclaration.getSuperTypes(KtLightClassForSourceDeclaration.kt:427)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ScopedClassHierarchy.calcImmediateSupersWithCapturing(ScopedClassHierarchy.java:163)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ScopedClassHierarchy.lambda$getImmediateSupersWithCapturing$2(ScopedClassHierarchy.java:148)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$2.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:112)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ScopedClassHierarchy.getImmediateSupersWithCapturing(ScopedClassHierarchy.java:148)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.getScopeCorrectedSuperTypes(PsiClassImplUtil.java:740)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.processSuperTypes(PsiClassImplUtil.java:750)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.processDeclarationsInClassNotCached(PsiClassImplUtil.java:724)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.processDeclarationsInClass(PsiClassImplUtil.java:479)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.lambda$processDeclarationsInClassNotCached$2(PsiClassImplUtil.java:725)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.processSuperTypes(PsiClassImplUtil.java:755)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.processDeclarationsInClassNotCached(PsiClassImplUtil.java:724)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.lambda$createMembersMap$1(PsiClassImplUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentFactoryMap$4.create(ConcurrentFactoryMap.java:224)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentFactoryMap.get(ConcurrentFactoryMap.java:63)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil$MembersMap.get(PsiClassImplUtil.java:359)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil$MembersMap.access$000(PsiClassImplUtil.java:351)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.processCachedMembersByName(PsiClassImplUtil.java:558)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.processDeclarationsInClass(PsiClassImplUtil.java:476)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.processDeclarationsInClass(PsiClassImplUtil.java:453)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassImpl.processDeclarations(PsiClassImpl.java:488)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiImportStaticReferenceElementImpl$OurGenericsResolver.resolve(PsiImportStaticReferenceElementImpl.java:238)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiImportStaticReferenceElementImpl$OurGenericsResolver.resolve(PsiImportStaticReferenceElementImpl.java:227)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.lambda$resolve$0(ResolveCache.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$2.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:112)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolve(ResolveCache.java:151)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:182)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiImportStaticReferenceElementImpl.multiResolve(PsiImportStaticReferenceElementImpl.java:223)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.processDeclarationsNoGuess(PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.java:377)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.processDeclarations(PsiJavaFileBaseImpl.java:312)
    at com.intellij.psi.scope.util.PsiScopesUtil.treeWalkUp(PsiScopesUtil.java:69)
    at com.intellij.psi.scope.util.PsiScopesUtil.treeWalkUp(PsiScopesUtil.java:51)
    at com.intellij.psi.scope.util.PsiScopesUtil.resolveAndWalk(PsiScopesUtil.java:218)
    at com.intellij.psi.scope.util.PsiScopesUtil.resolveAndWalk(PsiScopesUtil.java:149)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:492)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.access$100(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:47)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl$OurGenericsResolver.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:373)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl$OurGenericsResolver.resolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:365)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.lambda$resolveWithCaching$1(ResolveCache.java:205)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$2.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:112)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:204)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiImplUtil.multiResolveImpl(PsiImplUtil.java:724)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiImplUtil.multiResolveImpl(PsiImplUtil.java:715)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.multiResolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:424)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.advancedResolve(PsiJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:417)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassReferenceType.resolveGenerics(PsiClassReferenceType.java:191)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.JavaClassifierTypeImpl.resolve(JavaClassifierTypeImpl.java:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.JavaClassifierTypeImpl.isRaw(JavaClassifierTypeImpl.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolver.transformJavaClassifierType(JavaTypeResolver.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolver.transformJavaType(JavaTypeResolver.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaScope.resolveValueParameters(LazyJavaScope.kt:189)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaScope.resolveMethodToFunctionDescriptor(LazyJavaScope.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaScope$functions$1.invoke(LazyJavaScope.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaScope$functions$1.invoke(LazyJavaScope.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:448)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:523)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaScope.getContributedFunctions(LazyJavaScope.kt:242)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(LazyJavaClassMemberScope.kt:725)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getNonDeclaredFunctions(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:203)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.access$doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:448)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:523)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getNonDeclaredFunctions(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:203)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.access$doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:448)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:523)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$resolveToDescriptor$1.visitNamedFunction(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$resolveToDescriptor$1.visitNamedFunction(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtNamedFunction.accept(KtNamedFunction.java:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ResolveSession.resolveToDescriptor(ResolveSession.java:330)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.project.ResolveElementCache.functionAdditionalResolve(ResolveElementCache.kt:589)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.project.ResolveElementCache.performElementAdditionalResolve(ResolveElementCache.kt:317)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.project.ResolveElementCache.getElementsAdditionalResolve(ResolveElementCache.kt:178)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.project.ResolveElementCache.resolveToElements(ResolveElementCache.kt:222)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.resolve.ModuleResolutionFacadeImpl.analyze(ModuleResolutionFacadeImpl.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.resolve.ModuleResolutionFacadeImpl.analyze(ModuleResolutionFacadeImpl.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.resolve.ResolutionFacadeWithDebugInfo.analyze(ResolutionFacadeWithDebugInfo.kt:38)
    ... 25 more
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What version are you on? Also try updating to the most recent.

Comment: I was on 1.27 something and now updated to 1.3.11 but I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

File -> Invalidate Caches did the trick for me